# Script working when manually triggered but time trigger fails

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers

I have a google script to add the data of the latest csv file in google folder below the last row of data in a mastersheet. The script works well when I run it manually, however when I set up a time trigger, the script fails with error message:

ERROR
No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. at importData(Code:5)

My script is below. Can anyone assist? Thanks in advance.

```
function importData(folderID)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(my spreadsheet id);
  var folderID = (typeof(folderID) !== 'undefined')? folderID : 'my folder id';//default folderID
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = fldr.getFiles();
  var dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyyddMM");
  var re =new RegExp('^' + "11286321_" + dt + '.*\.csv$','i');
  while (files.hasNext())
  {
    var file = files.next();
    var filename = file.getName();
    if(filename.match(re))
    {
      var csvstr=file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
      var csvData=Utilities.parseCsv(csvstr);
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("EwayPayments");
      var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(lastrow + 1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
      file.setName(filename.slice(0,-3) + 'old');  //the .old files won't pass the file re filter next time. 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: About ``No item with the given ID could be found``, I'm not sure about the line that the error occurs. But if the IDs of ``my spreadsheet id`` and ``my folder id`` are correct, how about checking ``folderID`` when the script is run by the time trigger? Or how about testing by modifying from ``function importData(folderID)`` to ``function importData()``? If this didn't lead to the solution, I apologize.

Comment: Well if you are sure the ID's are correct then it can only be an authentication issue as the error says. How did you set up this time trigger??

Comment: @Tanaike That worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.